# How to execute process on events in Dell Boomi?

Tags: integration, boomi

Is there any way that the process is executed automatically on events.

Like I have one excel file, I read that excel file using disk connector(Start shape) then have used a custom script to convert it into a flat-file. But Is it possible that whenever anyone changes any data in the excel and the process gets triggers automatically?

Comment: Simple answer is no, however you can write a schedule process, that checks the modified date filter on files and retrive only those files whose modfied date > last execution run of that particular process. You would need Disk V2 for this.

Answer (score 0):

The Boomi API for execution record can be used for triggering alerts when predefined SLA’s for integration processes are not met.
The execution record API can be used to augment the information available in the event object or extracted independently into a reporting or analytics database for longer term historical analysis.
Note the execution record provides the process-level execution information.it does not provide document-level details including tracked fields.
Setup a corn job in the monitoring tool to periodically invoke the boomi API for “Execution Record”-query operation.
Set the input filter to select critical processes with additional arguments for status “INPROCESS”.

Check response XML returned for “execution duration”.Comare against pre-defined outer limits for said process. Trigger alerts based on result.